# Can we hardcode search query in code?

Tags: search, web

Is it legal to hardcode the web search query in the code and do the web searches.
For ex, Can I use the following queries in the code?

https://www.google.com/search?q=**searchkeyword**&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t
http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=**searchkeyword**

Thx!
Rahul.

Comment: It is legal and, yes, you can.  However tomorrow google may change their format - and you app won't work any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you means : you will upload this query as a link to browser to have a search query.

The answer is **YES**. You can use it. because it's something like a HTTP Post method, and you must follow by Google structure (and depend on other search engine you use), but maybe It will change sometime in the future. (But I think It rarely happen ;) )

And, your question, doesn't need tag `Android` because it` just a question about web application, and it's true not only for Google.